# Long date conversion

Tags: java, c#, date, date-conversion

I recently started supporting a system/application written in java.

I need to convert the below long date to a readable date as in 21 October 2016 :

```
Login date : 634940995544109969
Logout date : 63494125060775764
```

I tried different codes,I don't seem to come right. 
A solution can be in java or c#.

Comment: Do you have an example from the source on how that number is being generated?

Comment: Well what do those numbers represent? They don't look like milliseconds or even microseconds since the Unix epoch... where did you get those values from?

Comment: To convert you need to know more about `Login` and `Logout`.

Comment: Ahh, another  work assignment disguised as a question, even with the excuse "I tried, but nothing worked :'(".

Comment: The "63" at the beginning of both numbers agrees with the first two digits of the number of seconds between January 1, AD 1 and October 21, AD 2016 (63,612,604,800). The logout time is an order of magnitude less than the login date. So if it is a multiple of the number of seconds since January 1, AD 1, then the user logged in in modern times, but logged out about AD 200. Please tell us all about your time-traveling computer. Better still, propose it as new TV series.

Answer (score 0):

You must add L at the end of the input .

Try following code .

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long val = 634940995544109969L;
    Date date=new Date(val);
    System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date));
}
```

The output will be in readable format .
For Ex : The above code will give Mar 5, 20122449 as output .
The milli seconds are converted into date.

You can check the correctness of output in the below link

[Milliseconds to Date Conversion](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm)

Comment: Assuming that is `long`  representing milliseconds since epoch time

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert using below code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long lMilliSeconds = 634940995544109969L;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(lMilliSeconds);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
}
```

> Note-: I have considered that time is given in milliseconds.
>
> **Output-: Fri Mar 05 07:45:09 IST 20122449**

Answer (score 0):

try following in c#

```
 long a = 634940995544109969;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(a);
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
```